# Setting up Vaadin and Spring 3 - Autowiring fails (annotations)

Tags: spring, vaadin

I'm having some trouble using the @Autowire annotation of spring 3 in a vaadin application.

I have made a tiny test project with just a button which executes a method in an autowired service class.

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I click the button, because the service is never injected.

I have annotated the service with @Service("calculationService")

This is my application class:

```
package vaadinBaas;

// imports

public class MyVaadinApplication extends Application {

private Window window;

private CalculationService calculationService;

@Autowired
public void setCalculationService(CalculationService calculationService) {
    this.calculationService = calculationService;
}

@Override
public void init() {
    window = new Window("Show me the magic");
    setMainWindow(window);

    Button button = new Button("Click Me");

    button.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            window.addComponent(new Label(String.valueOf(calculationService.multiply(10, 10))));
        }
    });

    window.addComponent(button);
}
}
```

This is my spring application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:ct="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<ct:component-scan base-package="vaadinBaas" />
<ct:annotation-config />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

And finally my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Vaadin Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>vaadinBaas.MyVaadinApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: is **CalculationService** in the same package **vaadinBaas**?

Comment: it's in a subpackage "services".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try annotating MyVaadinApplication with Component annotation. Since MyVaadinApplication is not considered as spring managed class the Autowire didnt work for you. Also you need to load the bean definition xml using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and try calling getBean(MyVaadinApplication.class) so that all the autowiring happens automatically